# デプロイ後のファイルはどこにある？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, デプロイ

最近始めたばかりなのですが、ecサイトをデプロイしました。そこで質問なのですが、デプロイしたファイルはどこにあるのでしょうか？

今回デプロイしたアプリなのですが、aws(ec2)とrailsでやっているのですが、アプリに画像のアップローダーをつけていないため、画像が必要になると画像ファイルをassets/imageフォルダに用意しないといけないのです。しかしどこにあるかわからず、、、といった具合です。mac使っているのでfinderで検索してみたものの見つかりませんでした。
このような場合はどうしたらよいでしょうか？とりあえず必要な画像は全て置いてあるのですが、追加する必要が出てきた場合どうしたらよいかわからないので質問させていただきました。

何かお気付きの方いましたら宜しくお願いしますm(._.)m

Comment: デプロイに使用したライブラリとそのプラットフォームの構成(e.g. capistrano+ ec2, ecs, heroku, など) がないと、回答しようが無いと思います。質問にこの情報を追記していだだけますでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。無知なものでどれもわかりません＞＜
https://qiita.com/iwaseasahi/items/7af16215f06fbc57c490
このサイトをみながらデプロイしました。
どこを調べたらいいのでしょうか？